# Java write triangle on same row

Tags: java

I'm new in programming but I need a little help on my homework. Im trying to create 4 triangle using asterisk, which I have already done, one underneath each other, but I need them on the same row and thats the confusing part.

it should look like this

```
*        ********  ********
**       *******    *******
***      ******      ******
****     *****        *****
*****    ****          ****
******   ***            ***
*******  *                *
```

this is what I got so far

```
public class Practice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int row = 0; row < 11; row++) {

            for (int a = 0; a < row; a++)
                System.out.print("*");
            for (int star = 0; star < 2; star++)

                System.out.print("\t");

            for (int b = 10; b > row; b--)
                System.out.print("*");

            System.out.println();

        }

    }// end main method
}// end class Triangle
```

and this is the out put

```
        **********
*       *********
**      ********
***     *******
****        ******
*****       *****
******      ****
*******     ***
********        **
*********       *
**********
```

Comment: You should try this little bit more. It will help you to understand loop concept.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int max = 11;
for (int row = 1; row <= max; row++) {

    for (int a = 0; a <row; a++){
        System.out.print("*");
    }

    for (int star = max; star >=row; --star){
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

    for (int b = max; b >= row; b--){
            System.out.print("*");
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one to get output.

```
public class TriangleOnRow {
public static void main(String[] args){
int max = 11;
for (int row = 1; row <= max; row++) {

    for (int a = 0; a <row; a++){
        System.out.print("*");
    }

    for (int c = max; c >=row; c--){        
        System.out.print("  ");//2 whitespace's
    }

    for (int b = max; b >= row; b--){
            System.out.print("*");
    }

    for (int star = 0; star <=row; star++){        
        System.out.print(" ");//1 whitespace
    }
    for (int star = row; star >=0; --star){        
        System.out.print("   ");//3 whitespace's
    }

    for (int c = max; c >=row; c--){
            System.out.print("*");
    }

    System.out.println();
}
}
}
```